# How do I create a new notebook in OneNote that does not pull in sections from another notebook?

Tags: onenote

I would like to create a new notebook in OneNote.  As soon as I do this, my new notebook fills up with "misplaced sections" from other notebooks.  I am afraid that if I delete the misplaced sections in the new notebook that the deletions will synch back to other notebooks.

Is it possible to create a new OneNote notebook that is not related and does not synch with other notebooks.

My team at work uses OneNote on a daily basis.  I would like to create a notebook that contains a higher level of detail that is not automatically synch'd to the team notebook.  This will contain low-level notes that no one else will really need.

Is it possible to create a standalone notebook that does not endanger other notebooks with unintended synchs?

Answer (score 0):

For user questions, feel free to ping us @msonenote on twitter. I am unable to understand the issue you are facing, but I think if you provide us with a screenshot on our twitter, we'd be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks George - I cannot use twitter at work.  The basic issue is that when a new notebook is started, all of the sections from other notebooks show up as misplaced sections.  I don't want to risk other notebooks through an unintended sync if I delete the misplaced sections.  If possible, I would like to start a notebook that has no links to other notebooks.

Comment: Perhaps you can share a screenshot here (a link to an external file somewhere)?